# Stacking columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to set create a new column on my DataFrame grouping two existing columns

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

DATA=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,2), columns=['A', 'B'])
DATA['index']=np.arange(5)
DATA.set_index('index', inplace=True)
```

The output is something like this

```
       'A'          'B'
index
0      -0.003635    -0.644897
1      -0.617104    -0.343998
2       1.270503    -0.514588
3      -0.053097    -0.404073
4      -0.056717     1.870671
```

I would like to have an extra column `'C'` that has an `np.array` with the elements of `'A'` and `'B'` for the corresponding row. In the real case, `'A'` and `'B'` are already 1D `np.arrays`, but of different lengths. I would like to make a longer array with all the elements stacked or concatenated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If columns `a` and `b` contains numpy arrays, you could apply `hstack` across rows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

num_rows = 10
max_arr_size = 3
df = pd.DataFrame({
   "a": [np.random.rand(max_arr_size) for _ in range(num_rows)],
   "b": [np.random.rand(max_arr_size) for _ in range(num_rows)],
})
df["c"] = df.apply(np.hstack, 1)

assert all(row.a.size + row.b.size == row.c.size for _, row in df.iterrows())
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I was using `np.stack` and `np.hstack` in other parts of my module, but totally forgot about the `apply` function of `pandas`

Answer (score 1):

```
DATA['C'] = DATA.apply(lambda x: np.array([x.A, x.B]), axis=1)
```

pandas requires all rows to be of the same length so the problem of uneven pandas series shouldn't be present

Comment: Column name with spaces are ususally problematic, but You can replace lambda code with:
`np.array([x['A'], x['B']])` which should work

Comment: Thanks. I'm guessing that `x.A` notation is not able to handle well column names with spaces. Thanks for the TIP. I deleted the comment while editing by mistake. And Yes, A and B have the same number of rows. But for each row, A and B have different lengths. Let's say, DATA has 10 rows, and A has 1000 elements, and B has 200. The sizes are uniform, meaning for all rows in DATA, A has always 1000 elements and B has 200. I need a C with 1200

Comment: and BTW @w_sz, welcome to the community. Thanks for your contribution